# How to add up elements in pandas falling between a broader index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I would like to achieve the following: I'm given a pandas data frame where the index is a `Datetimeindex`. Now I'm having a broader index, i.e. with fewer dates, given. For example:

```
In [437]: import pandas as pd

In [438]: long_index = pd.date_range('20180101', '20181231', freq='M')

In [439]: short_index = pd.date_range('20180101', '20181231', freq='Q')

In [440]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 13, 1), index=long_index)

In [441]: df
Out[441]: 
             0
2018-01-31   1
2018-02-28   2
2018-03-31   3
2018-04-30   4
2018-05-31   5
2018-06-30   6
2018-07-31   7
2018-08-31   8
2018-09-30   9
2018-10-31  10
2018-11-30  11
2018-12-31  12

In [442]: long_index
Out[442]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30',
               '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31',
               '2018-09-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')

In [443]: short_index
Out[443]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-03-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-09-30', '2018-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='Q-DEC')
```

I would like to group the data frame based on the `short_index` and sum within the groups. That means, the first group would contain the Timestamps:

```
'2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31'
```

The sum of this group is: `1+2+3=6`. The second group would contain the Timestamps:

```
'2018-04-30','2018-05-31', '2018-06-30'
```

and has a sum of `15` and so on. Obviously, this should work for general long and short index. **With this I mean both or one or none of the two index can be irregular so that there is no frequency attached to it.** We can assume that the `short_index` always lies within `long_index`.

How can this be achieved in a pythonic elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need quarterly `sum`

```
df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.quarter).agg({0:'sum','index':'last'}).set_index('index')
Out[426]: 
             0
index         
2018-03-31   6
2018-06-30  15
2018-09-30  24
2018-12-31  33
```

From Paul H

```
df.resample('Q').sum()
```

Comment: I *think* the `.resample` method would shorten this quite a bit

Comment: yeah, `df.resample('Q').sum()`

Comment: @PaulH yep , it will :-)

Comment: @Wen many thanks for your answer. I think the resample won't work in general. It might be that there is no frequency in eiter the long or short index. The same applies to your first solution. The `df.index.quarter` assumes this frequency. Can this be done in a pythonic way for general index (irregular frequency). That's what I meant with " Obviously, this should work for general long and short index." I will edit that